# EventToCommand for SelectionChanged on ComboBox inside of DataGrid mvvm/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

How can I catch the Selection Changed event that fires on a `ComboBox` that is embedded into a `DataGridComboBoxColum`? I would like to use MVVM pattern for this so something like a `EventToCommmand` solution would be nice.

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ViewTemplate" Width="180" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ViewTemplate}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I would like to use something like this but don't know where/how to set it up in this particular case.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

As requested this is my full code for XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Views.ViewManager.ViewManagerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Views.ViewManager"
             xmlns:ex="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Wpf.Extensions"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GrimshawRibbon;component/Revit/Wpf/Style/GrimshawTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ex:DataGridEx x:Name="dgViews" 
                               Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" 
                               Margin="10" 
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Views, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                               CanUserAddRows="False" 
                               IsReadOnly="False" 
                               SelectionMode="Extended" 
                               SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                               SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedViews, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding CellEditEndingCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewType" Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewGroup" Binding="{Binding ViewGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="130" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewSubGroup" Binding="{Binding ViewSubGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="130" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                                        EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                                        Header="OnSheet" 
                                        Binding="{Binding OnSheet, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                        IsReadOnly="True" 
                                        Width="80">
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ViewTemplate" Width="180" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ViewTemplate}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectChangeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </ex:DataGridEx>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and view model:

```
public class ViewManagerViewModel : ViewModelBaseEx
{
    public ViewManagerModel Model;
    public ObservableCollection<ViewWrapper> Views { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ViewWrapper> ViewTemplates { get; private set; }
    public IList SelectedViews { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs> CellEditEndingCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectChangeCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewManagerViewModel(Document doc)
    {
        Model = new ViewManagerModel(doc);
        Views = Model.CollectViews();
        ViewTemplates = Model.CollectViewTemplates();
        CellEditEndingCommand = new RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(args => OnCellEditEnding(args));
        SelectChangeCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(args => OnSelectionChanged(args));
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logic for handling cell editing events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">DataGrid Row object.</param>
    private void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var wrapper = e.Row.Item as ViewWrapper;
        switch (e.Column.SortMemberPath)
        {
            case "Name":
                Model.ChangeName(wrapper);
                break;
            case "ViewGroup":
                Model.SetParameter(wrapper, "View Group", wrapper.ViewGroup);
                break;
            case "ViewSubGroup":
                Model.SetParameter(wrapper, "View Sub Group", wrapper.ViewSubGroup);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public override void Apply()
    {
        var vw = new List<ViewWrapper>();
        foreach (ViewWrapper v in SelectedViews)
        {
            vw.Add(v);
        }

        Model.Delete(vw);

        // update collection so that rows get deleted in datagrid
        foreach (ViewWrapper i in vw)
        {
            Views.Remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the MVVM pattern you don't handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the `ComboBox` element in the view.

Instead you should implement your selection changed logic in the setter of the `ViewTemplate` property, or in a method that you call from there, that gets set whenever a new item is selected in the `ComboBox`, .e.g.:

```
private ViewWrapper _viewTemplate;
public ViewWrapper ViewTemplate
{
    get { return _viewTemplate; }
    set { _viewTemplate = value; SelectionChanged(); }
}
```

This is one of corner stones of MVVM. Whenever the source property gets set by the view, the view model can perform some logic. The view only sets a property. It doesn't handle any event.

**Edit:** If this is not an option for some reason you should replace the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` because you cannot apply an `EventTrigger` to a `Style`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ViewTemplate" Width="180">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewTemplate.Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ViewTemplate}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Well I am not trying to handle it in the view. I am trying to set the binding in the view so that it can trigger appropriate command in the view model. Is that ok?

Comment: No. The point is that you shouldn't use an EventTrigger to invoke a command. You should invoke the command in the setter of the source property (ViewTemplate) as this one gets sets when the selection in the ComboBox changes.

Comment: But the `ViewWrapper` class is shared among more than one view model. if i hard wire it with an event then its useless to me in other view models. i would much rather like to contain this specific view functionality in a view. Why is using `Triggers` not a good MVVM practice?

Comment: In that case you should replace the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` because you cannot apply an `EventTrigger` to a `Style`. Please refer to my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be doing what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, OK this works. BUT, you can do this with a normal DataGridComboBoxColumn if the items in your list implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you subclass the ObservableCollection to subscribe to it's item's property change events and (possibly) expose those events as their own event, like "ItemChanged" etc. Then your XAML is waaayyy cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can add eventhandler to your combobox. I added to grid's showing event, you can add another event of course.

```
private void Grid1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{ 
  ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (cb!=null)
                { cb.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);

                    // now attach the event handler
                    cb.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
                }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is something like this
so inside your viewmodel, you will have something like

Viewmodel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
{
            _selectChangeCommand= new RelayCommand(OnSelectChange, CanSelectChange);

}
    private RelayCommand _selectChangeCommand;
    public ICommand SelectChangeCommand { get { return _selectChangeCommand; } }
    private bool CanSelectChange()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void OnSelectChange()
    {
        ..//do something in here when you change something in your combo box
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml.cs
do something like this:

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

In your ViewModel.xaml file

```
<ComboBox....>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
           <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding SelectChangeCommand }"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

One important thing is to make sure that your viewmodel.xaml knows where it references from so that it can see where the SelectionChangeCommand is located so it can do the binding. FYI, for the relaycommand, my advice is to use the Galasoft.MVVMlight so you don't have to implement relaycommand yourself.

Comment: so, this is the approach that I was looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't trigger my command. Is there anything else that i need to do here?

Comment: Post your code, i will take a look at it! One thing i can advice u to do is to look at the output window and look for the command name... the output window on the visual studio will tell u exactly why your command doesn't trigger

Comment: I posted full code for the ViewModel and View. Thank you for help!